# Insert a Google maps code into a table column

Tags: sql, google-maps

I use this query

```
$sq="UPDATE `contact` SET `".$pType."`='".$content."'";
```

it works fine but until I enter this code to the text area:

```
<iframe width="710" height="450" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Yenimahalle,+Gersan,+Ankara,+T%C3%BCrkiye&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=gersan+&amp;sll=39.982382,32.760887&amp;sspn=0.157578,0.308647&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Bat%C4%B1+Sitesi+Mh.,+Gersan,+Ankara%2FYenimahalle,+Turkey&amp;t=m&amp;ll=39.955543,32.696342&amp;spn=0.029607,0.060854&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Yenimahalle,+Gersan,+Ankara,+T%C3%BCrkiye&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=gersan+&amp;sll=39.982382,32.760887&amp;sspn=0.157578,0.308647&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Bat%C4%B1+Sitesi+Mh.,+Gersan,+Ankara%2FYenimahalle,+Turkey&amp;t=m&amp;ll=39.955543,32.696342&amp;spn=0.029607,0.060854&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

it updates but with missing information;

like this:

```
<iframe width="710" height="450" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q
```

What could be the possible problem? I'm stuck as I can't see anything.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column being updated? I expect this to be the reason for the string being truncated.

Comment: @GarethD
the type is longtext. i think its because of the special characters.

for example: the "&" character causes problem.however there are various special character in the code.i dont know how to avoid this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using the urlencode function when putting the data into the table and then using the urldecode function when pulling it out.  This will get rid of all the ampersands.

$sq="UPDATE contact SET ".$pType."='". urlencode($content) ."'";